# npm init @shopify/app@latest -- --template giving error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-cli

I am trying to create a new shopify app using node js and react.
I am using Spring CLI 3, and using
`npm init @shopify/app@latest -- --template "https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-node.git"`
this comand.

tried
`npm init @shopify/app@latest -- --template "https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-node.git"`
this comand. Should have created a node react project.
but getting [Initial Snapshot While npm package installing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SaPt.png)
[after some time this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuSwo.png)
these error..
EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\  │
│  35f2869b3dc7731e49321a7eae2ede84\app\web\frontend' ->                        │
│  'E:\shopify\test-app3\node_modules\shopify-frontend-template-react'

Comment: The error seems about "permissions". But definitely there is a need of more info in order to help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new app using Node and React by running the following command:

```bash
npm init @shopify/app@latest -- --template=node
```

Note: you can set the template as `node` instead of setting the URL.